Show that $L$ is not regular
Let $F$ and $L$ be arbitrary infinite binary languages
$\forall x,y\in F$ with $x\neq y$, there are 2 binary strings $w,z$ (possibly equal) such that $wxz\in L$ and $wyz\notin L$. Show that $L$ is not regular.
I've tried to use $F$ to construct some infinite fooling set for $L$, but with no success so far. Can anyone provide some hint on how such fooling set should look like?

It's not true if $F = \varnothing$. Otherwise there is no such $L$,. even nonregular: take $x = y$, you get that there should be string that is both in $L$ and not in $L$.

sorry I missed the condition that $x\neq y$. I've edited my question. @mihaild

That's still not true. For example, if $F$ is empty or contains only one element. Or if $F = {0, 1}$ and $L$ is language of words with odd number of $0$s.

@mihaild my bad. I also forgot to mention that $F$ and $L$ are infinite. I just double checked my question. It should be correct now.

Assume $L$ is regular and let $A$ be DFA recognizing $L$ with transition function $f$ and initial state $s_0$. Note that if for some $x, y$, $\forall s: f(s, x) = f(s, y)$ then also $\forall w,z: f(s_0, wxz) = f(s_0, wyz)$ and so $A$ either accepts both $wxz$ and $wyz$, or rejects both - in particular, it's impossible that $wxz \in L \wedge wyz \not \in L$.
So, if we can prove that there are $x, y \in F$ s.t. $\forall s: f(s, x) = f(s, y)$, we prove that $L$ isn't regular.
Let $g: F \to (S \to S)$, $g(x)(s) = f(x, s)$. As $F$ is infinite and $S \to S$ is finite, there is some $h \in (S \to S)$ s.t. for infinitely many $x \in F$, $g(x) = h$. In particular, there are two distinct $x, y \in F$ s.t. $g(x) = g(y)$.
More generally, if this property holds for some $F$ and regular $L$ that can be recognized by automata with $n$ states, this proof shows that $n^n \geq |F|$.

The syntactic congruence of a language $L$ of $A^*$ is the congruence $\sim_L$ defined on $A^*$ by $x \sim_L y$ if and only if
$$
 \text{ for all } u, v \in A^*,\ uxv \in L \iff uyv \in L
$$
The quotient monoid $A^*/{\sim_L}$ is called the syntactic monoid of $L$.
Now a language is regular if and only if its syntactic monoid is finite.
Since $F$ is infinite, your condition implies that the syntactic monoid of $L$ is infinite and hence $L$ is not regular.
Note. I gave the French Wikipedia entry as a reference, since it is preferable to the English version.
